# How to removed killed app from recently used list (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, automated-tests

I am developing a helper for an automated testing suite. There is a requirement to kill/reset the application being tested, so the app can be started again "fresh".

I know killing an app is against Apple guidelines; there are many questions here about that with sensible answers ("don't do that!"), but this is a different scenario; and the app will never be on the App Store (as it has been instrumented for testing purposes).

Currently, our helper calls "exit(0)" from within the app to terminate it.  This works fine, but the app icon is left in the recently used apps list (double click home button).

I need a way to programatically remove the icon from the list (or, terminate the app in such a way the icon does not remain). Or maybe a way of refreshing this list somehow. The only way I have found so far is to uninstall the app and install it again.

This must work on the device (as well as the simulator). I can use solutions that make use of USB-only functionality (e.g. provided by libimobiledevice and friends), or calling a function inside the app, or a Private API call. Assume the device has a development profile on it. Jailbreaking is not an option.

Comment: The recently used list is just that - a list.  If you have called `exit()` then you app isn't running and there is no difference in the launch process in your app between being on the recent list and not.  Uninstalling on the other hand removes all of your application's data and files

Comment: Thanks - yes, I agree, there is no difference in the launch process, but our testers are not as aware of this as you and I. To save confusion, we would prefer the app not showing in the recent list.